Add an image on a cylinder with wrinkles
I design a cylinder with wrinkles following this video: https://youtu.be/bNGGwaHOzHY?si=RODbCMi0yViRNy8X. Now I want to add an image on it but I don’t know how to do it because nothing works. Someone can help me?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Sorry, just saying "nothing works" without any information what all this nothing is you already tried is a bit vague. So you are basically asking how to texture a cylinder?

Have to say, at least on a brief viewing, the mapping in the tutorial is a bit odd. It would be better to map using UV, rather than index.  The same UV will be used for your image. Did you make the cylinder inside GN, or start with one that already existed?

@RobinBetts I made the cylinder as in the video because I needed to create an inflatable robotic arm and the result of that video is what I need. now I need to insert a png image that contains a transparent background. should i add image via uv? could it work?
